# Python Input between two other commands?

Tags: python, printing

I would like to have a login function, in which you have to enter your password. It would be great to have it like this:

```py
def login():
    print("---------")
    input("Password: ")
    print("---------")
```

But of course, the second print only appears if you entered your password.
I Know, there are already questions about this, but how can I do it uncomplicatedly?

Answer (score 1):

If they input nothing, the input will be an empty string, which is "falsy"

```
def login():
    print("---------")
    p = input("Password: ")
    if p: print("---------")
```